# DiscoveryClient unable to refresh its cache! Status 404

Tags: netflix-eureka, intershop

I have set up Intershop Commerce Management 7.8 and everything runs fine, except I get constant errors in the error log file.

Eureka is running, I can access the Eureka UI using http://localhost:8760
The application server and Solr is listed and running.

The URL in eureka-client.properties is set to:
http://localhost:8760/eureka

Any ideas what is wrong here?

Here some of the error entries:

```
[2017-03-07 10:39:10.865 +0000] ERROR localhost ES1 appserver0 [] [] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient [] [] [] [] "DiscoveryClient-CacheRefreshExecutor-0" DiscoveryClient_DEVELOPER-SOLRSERVER/localhost_appserver0 - was unable to refresh its cache! status = Bad status: 404 java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad status: 404
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.makeRemoteCall(DiscoveryClient.java:1589)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.makeRemoteCallWithFollowRedirect(DiscoveryClient.java:1460)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.makeRemoteCall(DiscoveryClient.java:1443)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.makeRemoteCall(DiscoveryClient.java:1394)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1136)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1042)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.access$2100(DiscoveryClient.java:123)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$CacheRefreshThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1900)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

[2017-03-07 10:39:14.269 +0000] ERROR localhost ES1 appserver0 [] [] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient [] [] [] [] "DiscoveryClient-CacheRefreshExecutor-0" Can't contact any eureka nodes - possibly a security group issue? java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad status: 404
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.makeRemoteCall(DiscoveryClient.java:1589)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.makeRemoteCallWithFollowRedirect(DiscoveryClient.java:1460)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.makeRemoteCall(DiscoveryClient.java:1443)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.makeRemoteCall(DiscoveryClient.java:1394)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1136)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1042)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.access$2100(DiscoveryClient.java:123)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$CacheRefreshThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1900)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

[2017-03-07 10:39:14.270 +0000] ERROR localhost ES1 appserver0 [] [] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient [] [] [] [] "DiscoveryClient-CacheRefreshExecutor-0" DiscoveryClient_DEVELOPER-APPSERVER/localhost_ES1_appserver0 - was unable to refresh its cache! status = Bad status: 404 java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad status: 404
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.makeRemoteCall(DiscoveryClient.java:1589)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.makeRemoteCallWithFollowRedirect(DiscoveryClient.java:1460)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.makeRemoteCall(DiscoveryClient.java:1443)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.makeRemoteCall(DiscoveryClient.java:1394)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1136)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1042)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.access$2100(DiscoveryClient.java:123)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$CacheRefreshThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1900)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a simple solution for this problem. The eureka client is just a bit fussy:
Use 'http://localhost:8760/eureka/' instead of 'http://localhost:8760/eureka'.
I hope that helps.

Comment: The "Cookbook - Eureka Deployment and ICM Configuration" document contains a small note: "This property [eurekaServerUrl] must end with a slash ("/")." (point 3.3)

Comment: I changed it in the following files and it solved the problem:
`./local/engine/tomcat/tomcat_inst/lib/eureka-client.properties`
`./local/webadapter/config/eureka-client.properties`
`./local/microservices/config/eureka-client.properties`
`./share/system/config/cluster/eureka-client.properties`

Answer (score 0):

Just you can add the following script inside your application.yml file and will work fine.

```
     server:
        port: 8761
 

    eureka:
      instance:
        hostname: localhost
      client:
        registerWithEureka: false
        fetchRegistry: false
        serviceUrl:
          defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/
```